# Pass generated HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, pyramid

I'm trying to pass a string of generated HTML from Python to Javascript. This is the simplified version of my view (using Pyramid framework).

```
@view_config(route_name='view_page', renderer='templates/page.jinja2', permission='view')
def view_cosmeceutical(request):
    gen_html = markdown( ingredient.desc )
    return dict(gen_html=gen_html)
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-python-flask-framework-to-javascript), I saw that I can use `{{ variable }}` in Javascript too, so in my JS file, I have a function that attempts to change the innerHTML of the element with the id 'content-desc'. But all I'm getting is the string {{ genHTML }} instead of the actual variable containing the generated HTML.

```
function insertHTML() {
    genHTML = '{{gen_html}}';
    $('#content-desc').html(genHTML);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On which file your function is written ? {{gen_html}} will be templated only in page.jinja2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to pass data and content from the server-side Python to JavaScript are

- JSON embeds in HTML
- Separate AJAX calls which serve JSON objects as `application/json` mime

For the embed approach, I would do somethibng along the lines to export data to the page template as JSON:

```
   import json

   gen_html = ...
   javascript_data = json.dumps(dict(gen_html=gen_html))
   return dict(javascript_data=javascript_data)
```

Then in the page template pass this to JavaScript global variables:

```
   <script>
          window.javascriptData = {{javascript_data}}; // Check need to escape HTML in your case
   </script>
```

And then in JavaScript (keep preferably in a separate static .JS file):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#content-desc').html(window.javascriptData.gen_html);
   });
```

Also, I would not generate HTML for just passing it to JavaScript in the first place. Instead, I would pass raw data to JavaScript as JSON, and then generate HTML on the client-side from this data using client-side templating. This increases the complexity, but is more "clean" and flexible.

Example microtemplating engines for the client-side JavaScript:

[DOM tree based JavaScript template engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282315/dom-tree-based-javascript-template-engines/9299643#9299643)

Comment: I'm generating HTML from Markdown on the server side using Python Markdown, so I'm not sure how to do that on the client-side instead (haven't found a good enough Markdown parser in JS). Following your code, ``window.javascriptData;`` gives an associative array ``{"desc_html": "<h2>Test</h2>
<p>This is the desc</p>"}`` , but ``window.javascriptData.gen_html;`` is ``undefined``.

Comment: It seems to be because ``window.javascriptData`` is actually a string, not an object...

Comment: Use View Source to find out what goes to your HTML file.